# Loop selection with imported models

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges

I imported a model of a credit card and want to round the edges with the bevel tool.
Is there a short way to select all the edges around the card without doing it manually edge by edge?

Loop select didn't work for me, even though the loop is fully connected and there are no double vertices.

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: select chunks by chunks with alt + click

Comment: there must be a problem somewhere in your faces chain if you can't select the ring, please share your file

Comment: If the Card is flat (without number/name geometry) the fastest way is to go to Top View (Num 7) and select with Select Box selection all the vertices and assign Bevel. Try also Mesh > Clean Up > Merge By Distance to merge the overlapping vertices to get more clean Alt+LMB selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select a face, press Shift G > coplanar, then go to Select Menu > Select Loop > Boundary Loop.

Another method, select a vertex, hold Ctrl, select another vertex: shortest path will be added.

[image]